# Is it possible to route rule1 response to rule2 in AWS Application Loadbalancer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, aws-application-load-balancer

I have an ALB with 2 rules. Rule1 has a target group of lambda which sends some authenticated data as response. I want to send that response to target group of Rule2. 
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible.

The load balancer will forward a request and will then return the response to the original requester.

Comment: Then how do i redirect to particular target group based on lambda's response? Any suggestions?

Comment: You might be able to return an HTML page with a redirect meta, so that the browser itself makes another request with different parameters.